# grep regex: search for any of a set of words

Tags: regex, grep

I want to search a large set of files for a set of words in any order, with or without spaces or punctuation.  so, for example, if I search `hello, there, friend`, it should match

```
hello there my friend
friend, hello there
theretherefriendhello
```

but not

```
hello friend
there there friend
```

I can't figure out any way to do this.  is it even possible to do using grep, or some variation of grep?

Comment: does it have to be exactly `hello` or `helloworld` is also ok?

Comment: `helloworld` is fine so long as the other words are also there. I'll update the question to clarify when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it even possible to do using grep, or some variation of grep?

You can use `grep -P` ie in `Perl` mode,the following regex.

```
^(?=.*hello)(?=.*there)(?=.*friend).*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/37

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/word1/{/word2/{/word3/p;};}' *.txt
```

Comment: This works in GNU sed, but not in OSX, FreeBSD, etc.  To make it portable, add a semicolon (`;`) before each close-curly-brace (`}`).

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose I wouldl use `awk` like this:

```
awk '/hello/ && /there/ && /friend/' file
```

This checks if the current line contains **all** the strings: `hello`, `there` and `friend`. If this happens, the line is printed

*Why? because then the condition is True and the default behaviour of awk when something is True is to print the current line.*

Answer (score 2):

In an Basic and Extended RE, without using vendor- or version-specific extensions like Perl RE, you would need to handle this using something like this:

```
egrep  -lr 'hello.*there.*friend|hello.*friend.*there|there.*hello.*friend|there.*friend.*hello|friend.*hello.*there|friend.*there.*hello' /path/
```

Note the `-l` option to tell you only filenames, and `-r` to tell grep to search recursively.  This solution should work on pretty much every variation of `grep` that you might come across.

This is obviously inelegant in terms of the RE, but handy in terms of using grep's built-in recursive search.  If the RE bothers you, I would use `awk` or `sed` for this instead, if you can, wrapped in `find`:

```
find /path/ -exec awk '/hello/&&/there/&&/friend/ {r=1} END {exit 1-r}'\; -print
```

Again, the output of this is a list of files, rather than a list of lines.  You can adjust to suit your specific requirements.